# PeerFinder.Start()

Tags: c#, networking, bluetooth, windows-phone-8

I'm investigating how the `PeerFinder.Start()` works on WP8 when I try to connect to an app-to-app scenario via Bluetooth. Anyone knows any method I record and decode this Bluetooth traffic emitted by my devices?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to record Bluetooth traffic on a WP8 device. I'm aware that's an option on Android, but it's not supported on WP8. I don't see why you'd need to do bluetooth profiling for phone-to-phone communication. If you're trying to do phone-to-device communication you'll need to the communication protocol spec of the packets expected by the device.

Comment: I need to find my custom built hardware moduls via bluetooth, which are not paired with my phone. I'm thinking to emulate my app and its communication on the custom build side, so my phone and app can (belive it is an other instance of my app and can)discover it. Basically I want to discover unpaired devices in wireless range.